# Como sair da listagem do git?

Tags: git

Estou com um projeto baixado pelo repositório do GitHub.

Quando executo o comando `git log` dentro desse projeto, ele me lista todas as *branches* existentes no projeto, porém não consigo sair da listagem.

Já tentei de tudo, já fiz <kbd>ESC</kbd> em teclado, já tentei <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, porém essas alternativas não funcionam, alguém teria uma sugestão?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pressione `q` para sair.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss muito obrigado funcionou, coloque como resposta para eu marcar como resposta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bem vindo ao `less`! Um paginador Unix que faz mais coisas que o `more`.

Você pode fazer muita coisa interessante com o `less`, como procurar por uma expressão regular com <kbd>/</kbd>. Mas, se seu interesse é apenas sair do programa, basta um <kbd>q</kbd>.

Esse é o mesmo paginador que você vê ao consultar o `man` de algum programa, como `man less`.

---

#### Detalhes extraídos dos comentários

Como bem lembrado pelo [@Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss), é possível configurar o seu paginador. E essa configuração pode ser feita por repositório (não apenas global).

Conforme documentação que o [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) cavou, basta setar a propriedade `core.pager` para fazer a configuração. [Leia a documentação oficial](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_code_core_pager_code).

Como nota de humor de programadores:

> You can set it [`core.pager`] to `more` or to your favorite pager (by default, it's `less`)

Em tradução livre (traduzindo até mesmo o nome dos programas):

> Você pode configurá-lo [`core.pager`] para *mais* ou para o seu paginador favorito (por padrão, é *menos*)

Comment: Jefferson, ele sempre usa o Less ou isso é configurável? Estava pesquisando sobre isso antes de responder.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é configurável, fica no `.git/config` na minha memória. Mas infelizmente eu perdi o link do SO internacional que falava sobre isso...

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss É configurável, basta setar o `core.pager` no `.git/config`: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_code_core_pager_code

Comment: @hkotsubo, adorei o jogo de palavras na documentação: "You can set it to `more` or to your favorite pager (by default, it’s `less`)"

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Pois é. O simples fato do `less` ser uma "evolução" do `more` já mostra como programadores têm um senso de humor peculiar :-)

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

```
CTRL+Z
```

Pode resolver o seu problema. Esse comando suspende os processos em questão, para encerra-los você pode apenas digitar `q`

Comment: `Ctrl+z` apenas suspende o processo, mas não o finaliza. Acredito que criar e manter múltiplos processos suspensos não será o desejado.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eita, não sabia disso! Obrigado Anderson, já fica a dica, será que deleto essa resposta?

Comment: Você pode editar e corrigir a informação, deixando claro isso. Provavelmente fazendo isso reverterá os votos na resposta.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu corrigi até para não passar desinformação, obrigado.